# How can I export a MySQL Database from Cloud9?

Tags: mysql, export, cloud9-ide

How can I export a MySQL Database from Cloud9, the online development IDE in the cloud. I was able to import a database, but I still haven't figured out how to export it, or download it to my computer, or anywhere else for that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysql-ctl cli
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO <username>@localhost;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'socket';
quit;

mysqldump -u<username> --protocol=tcp -S /home/ubuntu/lib/mysql/socket/mysql.sock  --all-databases > db.sql
```

There were two tricks.  First, mysqldump didn't let me run it as the regular root user, so I created my own username with full privileges.  Then, I looked up what socket it ran under.  Then, I specified that it should run with the tcp protocol.  That exported out all my sql tables.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to export the database by entering

```
mysqldump your_database_name > any_file_name.sql
```

at the cloud9 command line.

Comment: Here is my 2 cents: ```mysqldump your_database_name > any_file_name.sql -uyour_db_user_name -p```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting an error when I tried to import the exported database using the methods above. I found installing phpmyadmin works better when exporting for import to new server database. Here is a post on how to set it up.:
https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-phpmyadmin/1723